# Extract the text after a string for all occurrence excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string and I want to extract the country code after "country":

Data

```
[{"id":"123","country":"SG"}, {"id":"456","country":"DK"}, {"id":"789","country":"NZ"}]
[{"id":"123","country":"SG"}, {"id":"456","country":"DK"}]
[{"id":"123","country":"SG"}]
```

Output I want

```
SG DK NZ
SG DK
SG
```

Comment: Is that one long string in the same cell? Or is everything in a square bracket in a separate cell (or maybe even everything in curly brackets/quotes in a separate cell)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on below formula and let us know your feedback.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'country')]"),12,2))
```

[image]